# Adding value to global variable in a subshell is not working

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get the total disk usage of my machine. Below is the script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
totalUsage=0
diskUse(){
    df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
    do
       diskUsage=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
       totalUsage=$((totalUsage+diskUsage))
    done
}
diskUse
echo $totalUsage
```

While `totalUsage` is a global variable, I have tried to sum the individual disk usage to `totalUsage` in the line:

`totalUsage=$((totalUsage+diskUsage))`

An echo of `totalUsage` between `do` and `done` shows the correct value,
but when I try to echo it after my call `diskUse`, it stills prints a `0`

Can you please help me, what is wrong here?

Comment: You are running a sub-shell, variables tend to get lost during post its exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `totalUsage` in a sub-shell doesn't change the value in the parent shell.
Since you tagged bash, you can use *here string* to modify your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
totalUsage=0
diskUse(){
    while read output;
    do
       diskUsage=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 )
       totalUsage=$((totalUsage+diskUsage))
    done <<<"$(df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }')"
}
diskUse
echo $totalUsage
```

Comment: Why not [process-substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to insert

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

as new line after

```
#!/bin/bash
```

From `man bash`:

> `lastpipe`: If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell environment.